# my condition not satisfy end of forloop help me please

Tags: android

below ismy code is work fine only problem in last loop i wan to change little thing how i silll know is last loop?? my code not satisfy this conditon   if(i == school5.length()-1) at end of forloop and not replace , with . what i will doplease help me

```
JSONArray school5 = json2.getJSONArray("dish_ingredient");
String concatProduct = "";

for (int i = 0; i < school5.length(); i++) {
    String name = school5.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
    String subIngredient = school5.getJSONObject(i).getString("sub_ingredients");
    if(i == 0){
        if (subIngredient.equals(""))
        {
            if(i == school5.length()-1)
            {
                concatProduct = " "  + "<b>" + name +  "</b>"+". " +  subIngredient;
            }
            else
            {
                concatProduct = " "  + "<b>" + name +  "</b>"+", " +  subIngredient;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            concatProduct = " "  + "<b>" + name +  "</b>"+": " +  subIngredient; 
        }

    } else {
        if (subIngredient.equals(""))
        {
            concatProduct += " "  + "<b>" + name +  "</b>"+", " +  subIngredient;
        }
        else
        {

            concatProduct += " "  + "<b>" + name +  "</b>"+": " +  subIngredient; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should format your code so that others can read it properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (i == school5.length()-1)` will always be false because it is inside `if (i == 0)`

Comment: Great spot! Completely missed that due to the poor formatting

Answer (score 1):

This

```
if(i == school5.length()-1)
```

will never be true because before this condition will be checked only when `i==0`.

The only case when

```
if(i == school5.length()-1)
```

is true *when i == 0 & json array length is 1*

Answer (score 1):

Moreover it is a good practise to not keep that "school5.length();" in the for loop for better performance.

It should be better to deal with something like that

```
int size = school5.length();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   // your loop
}
```